# How to enable logging so messages kept internally until get/clear?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In an application I want to collect messages related to some dedicated part of the processing, and then show these messages later at user request.  I would like to report severity (e.g. info, warning), time of message, etc., so for this I considered to use the Python standard [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) module to collect the messages and related information.  However, I don't want these messages to go to a console or file.

Is there a way to create a Python logger, using `logging`, where the messages are kept internally (in memory) only, until read out by the application.  I would expect start of code like:

```
log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
... some config of log for internal only; not to console
log.error('Just some error')
... some code to get/clear messages in log until now
```

I have tried to look in [logging — Logging facility for Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html), but most example are for immediate output to file or console, so an example for internal logging or reference is appreciated.

Comment: You could write your own [handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#handler-objects) that implements such behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: But it looks like handlers can only be specified through `logging.basicConfig(handlers=...)` whereby it applies for logging in general, and not just a dedicated logger.  Is there a way to specify a handler for a logger created by `logger.getLogger`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"logging in general"* vs. a *"dedicated logger"*. Could you edit the question to clarify what you're doing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have updated the question with an initial description of the overall purpose... it is right to consider using the Python standard `logging` module for this?

Comment: Perhaps not, if you want to do something that changes the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use another handler. You could use a `StreamHandler` over an `io.StringIO` that would simply log to memory:

```
log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
memlog = io.StringIO()
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(memlog))
```

All logging sent to `log` can be found in `memlog.getvalue()`

Of course, this is just a simple Handler that concatenates everything in one single string, even if for versions >= 3.2 each record is terminated, by default with a `\n`. For more specific requirements, you could have a look at a `QueueHandler` or implement a dedicated `Handler`.

References: [logging.handlers](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.handlers.html) in the Python Standard Library reference manual.

Comment: The use of `io.StringIO` gives access to all the messages in a single string, but I kind of hoped for individual messages access, so the output could be formatted per message.

Comment: @EquipDev: for versions >=3.2, messages are delimited with `\n'. Pleas see my edit.

Comment: @EquipDev if raw `StringIO` doesn't suit you -- write a custom handler.